# Spring Console Command Line Application Integration Tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am trying to write the integration tests for my simple command line app

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Autowired
  ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Autowired
  MyService service;

 
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(VehicleCatalogPublisherApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext,
        () -> service.run());
  }
```

My Test

```
@SpringBootTest

    public class MyIntTest {
    
      @MockBean
      MyService service;
      
      @Test
      void contextLoads() {
        //verify the service call
      }
    
    }
```

I can see that from tests the app is started, but I am unable to assert the behavior in test method

Comment: Please don't use field injection, it's an antipattern. Use ctor injection instead. (see e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-field-injection-cons for an explanation) This also would allow you to make your test a regular unit test instead of a quite slow `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: Well you do a `System.exit` (which isn't really needed) which will kill your process.

Answer (score 0):

What you show as a test is not an integration test. An integration test would acutally call the executable and see if it behaves correctly "from the outside" but would not involve mocking (at least not at that level of `@MockBean` annotations).

Luckily what you want is also not an integration test, but a real unit test that checks if a method interacts with its peers in the expected way. As you test a method that calls `System.exit` it's a tough thing - but you could prepare a regular mock (e.g. with Mockito), doesn't have to be a full `@MockBean`, and configure it to be a stub that actually throws an exception when it's called. Then in your test you can configure the mock to be a stub that throws an exception - which you can expect in your test case to pass.

Downside is that if the exception doesn't throw (test fails) the `System.exit` will be executed. You could prevent this with `java.lang.SecurityManager` but it's deprecated and planned for removal from Java 17 on, without a proper replacement to prevent `System::exit` yet (see [JEP 411](https://openjdk.org/jeps/411)), so expect Warnings for now if you do that and also to change your code in the future, when the `SecurityManager` has gone.